# double gets converted into cell while converting to dataset - why?

Tags: matlab, variables, dataset, double, cell

My data:

```
me

me =

    2.0000  637.4976  660.8218  670.1036
    3.0000  617.1771  608.4111  616.0435
    4.0000  548.9677  563.2750  555.2890

class(me)

ans =

double
```

Why does this work, and creates a dataset with 4 variables...

```
dataset( {me, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' } )

ans = 

    a    b         c         d     
    2     637.5    660.82     670.1
    3    617.18    608.41    616.04
    4    548.97    563.27    555.29
```

...but this does not?

```
vars = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
dataset( {me, vars } )

ans = 

    Var1                          
    [3x4 double]    {1x4 cell}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

```
dataset( {me, vars{:} } )
```

`vars` is a cell array of four strings, whereas `vars{:}` is a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?s_tid=doc_12b) of those strings, which is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

In your first statement, you are trying to combine double variables with string variables.

Whereas in the second statement, you are trying to combine double variable with a cell array.

In order to get your second statement behave like the first, you need to access the individual elements of the cell array, this can be accessed through with `{:}` as explained here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html